# How is "Forwarding can be also done through Unix sockets" done?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, socket

https://zaiste.net/ssh_port_forwarding/#remote-port-forwarding

> Remote port forwarding is created with -R parameter.
>
> ```
> ssh -R source_port:forward_to_host:destination_port via_host
> ```
>
> This command connects to via_host. via_host runs a SSH server. It then
>   forwards all connection attempts to source_port on the remote via_host
>   machine to **destination_port port on the local machine (a machine that
>   initiated the ssh command)** . forward_to_host machine must be reachable
>   from the the local machine machine. Forwarding can be also done
>   through Unix sockets.

What does "Forwarding can be also done through Unix sockets" mean? 
How is that done?

Is ssh remote port forwarding  done not through Unix sockets, but Internet sockets?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Let's look at the real `ssh(1)` man page instead of that webpage:

```
 -R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport
 -R [bind_address:]port:local_socket
 -R remote_socket:host:hostport
 -R remote_socket:local_socket
```

There are four forms of the `-R` option, and the one you quoted is the first one. It forwards a TCP port on the system that has the remote end of the SSH connection to the specified host and TCP port number on the local side of the connection.

The second form describes how to forward a remote TCP port to a local Unix socket:

```
ssh -R 1234:/tmp/local_socket user@remote_host
```

In other words, when something connects to TCP port 1234 on the `remote_host`, the connection will be forwarded to Unix socket `/tmp/local_socket` on the local host.

The third form describes how to do it the opposite way, remote socket to a TCP port on the local side:

```
ssh -R /tmp/remote_socket:1234:somehost user@remote_host
```

Here, a process on remote_host can use Unix socket `/tmp/remote_socket` and the connection will be passed through the SSH connection to the local side, and then over a regular TCP connection to TCP port 1234 of `somehost`.

The fourth form describes forwarding from a remote Unix socket to a local one:

```
ssh -R /tmp/remote_socket:/tmp/local_socket user@remote_host
```

Here, a process on `remote_host` could open the Unix socket at `/tmp/remote_socket` to connect to `/tmp/local_socket` on local host.